# Can you get the properties from a file embedded in a .net assembly?

Tags: .net, reflection

When you embed a file in a .net assembly, are the file properties (such as last modified date, etc.) preserved? If so, How can you access these values?

I looked at `GetManifestResourceInfo` but that doesn't appear to provide this.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, as no-one has responded in 5 months, that the answer is: No this information is not stored in the assembly, and therefore cannot be retrieved at runtime.